# How do I get a Web-view to switch sites when pressing different side of UISegmentedControl (iOS Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I think all of the tutorials I found are from before you could use a xib with uisegmented control. Basically, I am just trying to load websites, that will switch when tapping between UISegmentedControls.

FYI, this is the way I am loading the websites:

```
    NSURL *USurl = [NSURL URLWithString:USurlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *USrequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:USurl];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webview loadRequest:USrequestObj];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a XIB, you have to bind the valueChanged event to a function on your file owner for example.

That function will be called when the segmented control value change, for example:

```
- (IBAction)segValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)seg {
  switch (seg.selectedSegmentIndex) {
     ....
  }
}
```

If you're doing this by code you can add an event listener to your segmented control with:

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(action:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

P.S.: Variable names, by convention, start with a lowercase character...

Answer (score 0):

Create a method(let's call it `-(void)switchBetweenTheViews:(id)sender`) and then add the following line to the code where you create the `UISegmentedControl`:

```
[yourSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(switchBetweenTheViews:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then whenever a user will tap on the other side of that `UISegmentedControl` this method will be called. Example of that method would be:

```
-(void)switchBetweenTheViews:(id)sender {
  UISegmentedControl *sc = (UISegmentedControl*)sender;
  NSURL *USurl;
  if (sc.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    USurl = [NSURL URLWithString:USurlAddress];
  } else {
    USurl = [NSURL URLWithString:USurlAddress2];
  }
  NSURLRequest *USrequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:USurl];
  [webview loadRequest:USrequestObj];
}
```

Hope it helps